# Abbreviating numbers in Android, locale sensitive

Tags: java, android

In my Android project, I am hoping to find a way to abbreviate numbers that is sensitive to various locales. If the number is less than 1000, it is to remain as is; otherwise, I would like the number divided by the largest possible power of 1000 and rounded to two decimal places. So far, I have the below code, which correctly produces the desired results as stated under Output.

```
public void formatNumbers() {
    //Output:
    //842 => 842
    //24,567 => 24.57k
    //356,915 => 356.92k
    //7,841,234 => 7.84M
    //1,982,452,873 => 1.98B
    int[] i = new int[] {842, 24567, 356915, 7841234, 1982452873};
    String[] abbr = new String[] {"", "k", "M", "B"};
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    for (long i1 : i) {
        int thousands = thousands(i1);
        String result;
        if(thousands == 0) {
            result = String.valueOf(i1);
        } else {
            double d = (double) i1 / Math.pow(1000.0, thousands);
            result = df.format(d)+abbr[thousands];
        }
        System.out.println(i1 + " => " + result);
    }
}
public int thousands(double num) {
    //returns the number of times the number can be divided by 1000
    int n=0;
    double comp=1000.0;
    while(num>comp) {
        n++;
        comp*=1000.0;
    }
    return n;
}
```

My concern is that I want a way to ensure that the output is sensitive to locale. If I understand correctly, DecimalFormat should take care of conventions such as commas instead of decimals where applicable; this leaves my concern with the suffix. While my output would be generally be understood in the United States for casual purposes (despite the fact that "M" is used to mean "thousands" in some industries, such as finance) and, from my understanding, many areas in Europe which have languages based on Latin, there are many locales that this would not be understood well. Perhaps there is a built-in function that handles this that I have not been able to find. Thank you in advance for your attention to and input on this task.

Comment: Apparently using NumberFormat is the way to go, check it out here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html

For example, to get number formatting in French, use:

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);